# How to add a page in Android Studio that connects to a button?

Tags: android, button

This is my first time using Android Studio, so please let me know if there is a very simple way to add a new page using buttons for my android app. If you click the button it should lead you to a new file with other code. Thank You so much!

Comment: You need to add a new `Activity` to your project and then call `startActvity()` on button click. Look it up on SO

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a layout with a button in it
2. Create two activities
3. setContentView(R.layout.your_xml) on one of the activities
4. Set up the buttons onClickListener

Code for step 4:

```
//initialize buttons
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_location);


            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new intent, and start it inside of the onclickListener of that button. Don't forget that on the intent you need to put the main activity from where you want to launch the new activity and the class (new page) that you want to launch.

I think that this link can help you.

[Starting new Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

I hope this helped you :)